# how to update column based on condition

Tags: sql, db2

i have a requirement to update a column in a table, if the column has null or value which is not like input.

Is it possible to do it in a single sql query.? my db is db2

i have tried the below one, but even if the change is not there, it is updating. i dont want that .

```
UPDATE ABC 
SET AG = CASE 
  WHEN AG IS NULL
    OR AG <> 1000010 
  THEN 1000010
  ELSE AG
END, 
     P = CASE 
  WHEN P IS NULL 
    OR P <> 1235
  THEN 1235
  ELSE P 
END
WHERE c = 607
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but how exactly this is different from just `UPDATE abc SET AG = 1000010, P = 1235`?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to update rows that already have the value?  Are you trying to avoid executing a database trigger?  Regardless, I think two update statements is probably the way to go.

Comment: Or, are you updating another column (like update_timestamp)?  Either way, I suggest editing your sql to better model your actual problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try moving the conditions to the WHERE clause:

```
UPDATE ABC 
SET AG = 1000010 ,
    P = 1235
WHERE c = 607 and
      (AG IS NULL OR AG <> 1000010 or
       P is NULL or P <> 1235
      )
```

This should minimize the calls to the trigger.